# Laravel 5 Route not Found in RouteServiceProvidor

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\Route' not found in /home/****/**********/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php on line 28



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'App\Providers\Route' not found
```

Above is the error of which I am seeing whenever attempting to run Artisan.  It seems that the issue has to do with my Filters (I am attempting to migrate from Laravel 4 to 5), and Namespacing.  I have two namespace's for which I want all of these filters to apply to: "App\Http\Controllers\API\V1" and "App\Http\Controllers\API\V2", but cannot for the life of me understand how to set this in the RouteServiceProvidor file.  Below is the code from RSP.php up to the relevant line.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        //Challenges
        Route::filter('challenge_general_permission', function($route)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AlanStorms answer is totally correct but I wanted to add that you don't even have to use the `Route` facade. Especially in this case where you have the `$router` object directly available. By the way: `Router` is the underlying class of the `Route` facade. I'd do this instead of what you have now:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    //Challenges
    $router->filter('challenge_general_permission', function($route)
```

Answer (score 10):

Your PHP file is in the `App\Providers` namespace.

```
namespace App\Providers;
```

You attempted to use a global class `Route` with a relative class name reference.

```
Route::filter('challenge_general_permission', function($route)
```

When you do this, PHP assumes you want the class `App\Providers\Route`.   There's no such class -- PHP dies.  You either need to tell PHP you want the global class `Route`

```
\Route::filter('challenge_general_permission', function($route)
```

or import `Route` into the current namespace

```
namespace App\Providers;
//...
use Route;
```